# how to write Regular Expression in MySQL select queries?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I tried this expression `/\b(word\w*)\b/i` to compare a `word` against the list of other words to find the duplicates. I used `preg_math_all()` and it worked fine. I wanted to do the same thing but this time check against the words retrieved from mysql database. This is what i wrote

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE word = /\b(word\w*)\b/i
```

this didnt worked.

Answer (score 7):

MySQL [regex syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) is a different from PHP's, you don't need the delimiters at the start and end.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE word REGEXP '\b(word\w*)\b'
```

You can't use the `i` flag for case insensitivity the same way as in PHP, as in MySQL whether the regex is case sensitive or not depends on whether the column collation is a case sensitive one or not.

Answer (score 6):

Your query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '/\b(word\w*)\b/i'
```