# MYSQL Using AND and Wildcard

Tags: mysql, wildcard

SQL statement is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cigardata 
WHERE Brand LIKE '$brandS' 
  AND Style LIKE '$styleS' 
  AND Wrapper LIKE '$wrapperS' 
  AND UPC LIKE '$upcS';
```

User inputs **Brand** and **Wrapper** only and it will return nothing, normal since nothing in the other 2 fields. If I fill all 4 fields of course it works perfect. What can be used in the other 2 fields as a wild card to satisfy that all 4 fields are filled and return a result? I have tried %.%, %''%, %*%. Any suggestions......

Comment: just don't add `AND field like "$field"` for non defined ones?

Comment: For matching anything, you can use just a single '%'. But the first comment is a better solution to your specific problem.

Comment: the program should build the query dynamically based on the user input.

Comment: So if you have "user inputs", where are they? What kind of application is this? We need more information before we can help you. There are various ways to solve this, but we need more information.

Comment: It is a combination of HTML and PHP. User inputs are via a text box in the HTML part and then in the PHP part: $brandS=$_POST["brandS"]; Also there are precautions take to prevent SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

isaace answer was the clue, the word "dynamically" led me to a solution that has been answered previously. Had to tweek it a bit with single quotes on the {$field1} to '{$field1}' and so on with the field 2 field 3 etc. [Crating a Dynamic Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251727/creating-a-dynamic-search-query-with-php-and-mysql)